# Configure key signals from keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I just bought a LG Z355 Ultrabook, ripped off Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu, wich is working perfectly. It has an ABNT2 keyboard layout with 4 keys in the right side of the keyboard to give fast access to win8 functionalities.

I'd like to use those keys as Pg UP, Pg Down, Home and End. Well, there are other keys that I'd like to change what they do. Another example: the only way to type / is via (Alt Gr + Q), I think I could use the Popup Menu key, wich is in the down right side.

Well, is there any way that I can determina the signal sent by a specific key in my keyboard arbitrarily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Autokey is a utility for linux that supports key remapping and automation, and might be of help.
http://code.google.com/p/autokey/